# F# Extension Methods on Lists, IEnumerable, etc

Tags: f#, methods, extension-methods, static-methods, c#-to-f#

In C#, if I had a widget definition, say:

```
class widget
{
    public string PrettyName() { ... do stuff here }
}
```

and I wanted to allow for easy printing of a list of Widgets, I might do this:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static PrintAll( this IEnumerable<Widget> widgets, TextWriter writer )
    {
        foreach(var w in widgets) { writer.WriteLine( w.PrettyName() ) }
    }  
}
```

How would I accomplish something similar with a record type and a collection (List or Seq preferrably in F#).  I'd love to have a list of Widgest and be able to call a function right on the collection that did something like this.  Assume (since it's F#) that the function would not be changing the state of the collection that it's attached to, but returning some new value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exactly analogous solution isn't possible in F#.  F# extension members can only be defined as if they were members on the original type, so you can define F# extensions on the generic type `IEnumerable<'T>`, but not on a specific instantiations such as `IEnumerable<Widget>`.

In C#, extension methods are often used to provide a more fluent coding style (e.g. `myWidgets.PrintAll(tw)`).  In F#, you'd typically just define a let-bound function and use the pipeline operator to achieve a similar effect.  For example:

```
module Widget =
  let printAll (tw:TextWriter) s =
    for (w:Widget) in s do
      writer.WriteLine(w.PrettyName())

open Widget
let widgets = // generate a sequence of widgets somehow
let tw = TextWriter()
widgets |> printAll tw
```

Comment: How would I define the printAll function as a member on the Widget Record type for use in the above scenario?

Comment: @flevine100 - You would typically _not_ define printAll as a member on a type, but as a let-bound function in a module.  I've edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: thanks! - Functional Programming is definitely a different way of thinking about code organization.